# How do python ctypes process c_char_p when '\0' appears in the middle of string

Tags: python

How does `a` get the whole str `hello \0 world`?

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> c=b'hello \0 world'
>>> a=ctypes.c_char_p(c)
>>> a
c_char_p(44440112)
>>> a.value
'b'hello
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question instead of its screenshot

Comment: already post the code, thank you

Comment: On the second line, what is `b`? a variable previously used?

Comment: @nicolallias `b'hello \0 world'` is a bytestring

Comment: The `ctypes` module defines `c_char_p` as the C datatype `char *` (NUL terminated). So the behaviour you are seeing is as defined. Maybe you need to look at the `struct` module.

Comment: Indeed, I did knew that. I just tried your code on my computer, I get the truncated value as well. From the documentation, it appears that it truncates on purpose on `\0` https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char_p  Do you want it to not truncate?

Comment: yes, i want the whole string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099077/how-do-you-convert-a-char-with-0-value-bytes-into-a-python-string give me the answer